# Nomenclature of Coordination compounds containing nitrogen

Tags: nomenclature

As Per rules , amine when present as a ligand is written as "ammine" with double m's , so a compound having a complex ligand such as ethane-1,2-diamine , will be written with 1 'm' amine or double 'm' ammine?

Answer (score 1):

As per rules, double m is used when the ligand is just $\ce{NH3}$, ammonia:

Cite from IUPAC Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry, Recommendations 2005:

> IR-7.1.3 **Representing ligands in additive names**
>
> Additive names are constructed by placing (sometimes modified) ligand names as prefixes
>   to the name of the central atom. For anionic ligands, the anion endings ‘ide’, ‘ate’ and ‘ite’
>   (see Section IR-5.3.3) are changed to ‘ido’, ‘ato’ and ‘ito’, respectively,
>   when generating
>   these prefixes. Names of neutral and cationic ligands are used unchanged, except in a few
>   special cases, most notably water (prefix ‘aqua’), ammonia (prefix ‘**ammine**’), carbon
>   monoxide bound through carbon (prefix ‘carbonyl’), and nitrogen monoxide bound through
>   nitrogen (prefix ‘nitrosyl’) (cf. Section IR-9.2.4.1).

E.g. in $\ce{[CoCl(NH3)5]^{2+}}$ pentaamminechloridocobalt(2+).

For amines, the ligand name is unchanged, e.g.
$\ce{[Co(en)3]^{3+}}$ tris(ethane-1,2-diamine)cobalt(3+).